# Matching Records and iterate through sub forms in access

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access, matching

I have a main form `MForm` which has a `subform A` and that `subform A` has another subform `subform B` inside.

"MForm" contains IDs based on the dates. (main record set. Distinct dates)
The `subform A` (Linked by "ID" and "DateR"  to the main form) is the one where I have to enter countries in four different columns namely AR, IR, SR, ER. These fields are number fields and needs to be updated manually by the user.
the `subform B`  which is under the above mentioned `subform A` (Linked by date and country) has a queried data from which i have numbers for AR_Count, IR_Count, SR_Count and ER_Count respectively. (Queried by "DateR" and "Country" from an excel query)

Now the purpose is i have an additional field in `Subform A` which is a field list and has two values "Matched" and "Unmatched". 
What i want to accomplish is when the numbers for AR,IR,SR and ER inputted by user in `Subform A` are equal to the numbers in AR_Count,IR_Count,SR_Count and ER_Count respectively in `Subform B` then the value for the field list should automatically change to "Matched". Now i need that to be for all records in that subform for that entry. 
Secondly, when all the records in the subform have matched in status field then the mainform "MForm" has a field called Status as well. with values "Active" and "Closed" . I want that once all the fields have values "Matched" in `Subform A` then in the MForm status should change to "closed" else it stays active.

I have included a picture to show how my form looks like . The user must select a date and fill the `Subform A`. `Subform B` has values pulled from a query.

Now i want a VBA Code and i want to ask how i can achieve these functions in my form. additionally where i can use that. I tried using `after update` or `before update` handlers for status fields with no luck.
[FORM LAYOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vP3f.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code you already have, and point out what exactly isn't working. Is your code not being called? Is it malfunctioning? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but people here can help you to spot problems.

Comment: its not about the code itself but i want to ask as to how i can achieve  the above explained result. How can i see to it that i can apply validations in such a way with two sub forms

Comment: DLookup("[CounType]", "iL/iW Summary", ("[Country] Like '" & Me.Country & "'") And ("[DateReceived] Like '" & Me.Date_Received & "'") And ("[Type] Like '" & "AR" & "'"))

Comment: The above VBA code is one which i want to place in the AR_Afterupdate field in my current form. where i want to lookup the value of CounType in the table iL/iW Summary. I want the current input country to match with the one in iL/iW Summary table and the date received to match as well. i tried this with error: data type mismatch.

Comment: I checked Country is string in both and datereceived as date in both the form and the table. I am trying to use this lookup to validate against the value that users fill in  the form.